# Android Button Vertical Padding?

Tags: android, button, padding

this is my code:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="nice"
            android:paddingVertical="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
            app:strokeWidth="2dp"
            app:strokeColor="@color/light_grey"
            app:cornerRadius="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"/>
```

And this is the button.

[Image of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvcZi.png)
It has a vertical space which is apparently not the padding and makes the button smaller than 40dp. I dont want to solve this problem by increasing the height of the button.

Comment: You might want to try marginTop or paddingTop properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the [Insets](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Insets#bottom) properties, so in your button add:

```
android:insetTop="0dp"
android:insetBottom="0dp"
```

There is also `insetLeft` and `insetRight` if you need them

Comment: Simple answer and exactly what I needed. Thanks!